# Using cin.get() in a loop to input a string

Tags: c++

I was wondering if there is a way of using the cin.get() fuction in a loop to read a string that could be composed of more than one word.

For example

```
while (cin.get(chr)) // This gets stuck asking the user for input

while (cin.get(chr) && chr != '\n') // This code doesn't allow the '\n' to be read inside the loop
```

I want to be able to read a whole string and be able to use my chr variable to determine if the current character being read is a '\n' character.

I'm a little familiar with the getline function. But I don't know of a way to individually go through every character in the string while counting them when using the getline. I hope what I'm saying makes sense. I'm new to programming and c++.

I basically want to determine when these characters ( ' ' , '\n') happen in my string. I will use this to determine when a word ends and a new one begins in my string.

Comment: "*I will use this to determine when a word ends and a new one begins in my string*" - then why not read the input word-by-word instead? That is how `operator>>` reads by default, ie `string word; while (cin >> word) { ... }`. Or, if you want to read words in a single line: `string line, word; while (getline(cin, line)) { istringstream iss(line); while (iss >> word) { ... }}`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to read a whole line and count the spaces in it you can use [getline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline).

```
std::string s;
std::getline(std::cin, s);

//count number of spaces
auto spaces = std::count_if(s.begin(), s.end(), [](char c) {return std::isspace(c);});
```

`std::getline` will always read until it encounters an `\n`.

Comment: why not simply `auto spaces = std::count(begin(s), end(s), ' ');`?

Comment: Because there are more characters than ' ' that can be classified as a space. For example a tab. I agree that it might be more than is needed in most cases.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't familiar with the purpose of `std::isspace`.

Comment: "*`std::getline` will always read until it encounters an `\n`*" - or a user-defined delimiter. `\n` is just the default delimiter

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
using namespace std;

int main() {
    char ch;
    string str = "";
    while (cin.get(ch) && ch != '\n')
        str += ch;
    cout << str;
}
```

and the string str would have all characters till end line.